# Binary Search Tree - Insert Method - Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Beginner to python here. I'm trying to create an insert method for a binary search tree. When I give the root an integer to start with rather than just passing self.root = BinaryTreeNode(), the insert method works. Can you tell me how I can accomplish this without passing an integer? Thanks!

```
class BinaryTreeNode:

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self, root = None):
        self.root = BinaryTreeNode()
        self.count = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.inOrder())


    # insert
    def insert(self, data):
        self.root = self.recursiveInsert(data, self.root)
        self.count+=1

    def recursiveInsert(self, data, node):
        if node is None:
            node = BinaryTreeNode(data)
        else:
            if data < node.data:
                if node.left is None:
                    node.left = data
                else:
                    self.recursiveInsert(data,node.right)
            else:
                if node.right is None:
                    node.right = data
                else:
                    self.recursiveInsert(data,node.left)

bst = BinarySearchTree()
bst.insert(5)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
in <module> bst.insert(5)
line 15, in insert self.root = self.recursiveInsert(data, self.root)
    if data < node.data:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you never consider the base case of a new tree.  Add this middle clause to your insertion:

```
    if node is None:
        node = BinaryTreeNode(data)
    elif node.data is None:
        node.data = data
    else:
        if data < node.data:
        ...
```